# Using WebAuthenticationBroker for oAuth

Tags: c#, windows-8, oauth, microsoft-metro

I want to use WebAuthenticationBroker for oAuth with Pocket (http://getpocket.com). The Pocket API is described at http://getpocket.com/developer/docs/authentication. The problem is the redirect uri. In their samples it is set to a custom protocol for iOS and Android. How do you deal with that on WinRT?

It does not work when I supply an empty redirect uri. When I supply an uri like http://www.google.sk, I see the authorization dialog for pocket, I authorize my app and I am redirected to http://www.google.sk. But the windows does not dismiss, I can only click the back button and that causes the WebAuthenticationResult to be Canceled.

Comment: Any suggestions for [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/40084724/2404470)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The WebAuthenticationBroker needs a Callback URI. If this URI is called within the web view, *the host ends the navigation and signals the broker* - as described in the [web authentication broker workflow at MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh750286.aspx).

The Pocket API `redirect_uri` you are submitting as a POST parameter should be the same as `WebAuthenticationBroker.GetCurrentApplicationCallbackUri`.

You can specify it as the third parameter in:

```
WebAuthenticationBroker.AuthenticateAsync(options, requestUri, callbackUri)
```

By the way:

If you need a simple wrapper for the Pocket API, I've built one for C# called [PocketSharp](http://pocketsharp.frontendplay.com)

Comment: Any suggestions for [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/40084724/2404470)

Answer (score 1):

I believe the answer is that you have to make your redirect URI ms-app:// for WebAuthenticationBroker to work.